Zero-shot winCLIP from anomalib not working
Following the recent advance in Anomaly classification/segmentation, I wanted to try the new winCLIP model, of which the anomalib library also has an implementation.
How to test zero-shot or to give a couple "normal/healthy" images for few-shot? As this is a zero-shot model, i would assume that this would easily work out of the box, but I can't get it working. Here is my current code:
from anomalib.models.image import WinClip
from anomalib.engine import Engine


# Import the datamodule
from anomalib.data import Folder
from anomalib.data.utils import TestSplitMode

# Create the datamodule
datamodule = Folder(
    name="lasercut_plank",
    root="./DATA_0shot",
    normal_dir="normal",
    test_split_mode=TestSplitMode.NONE
)

# Setup the datamodule
datamodule.setup()

# Access the datasets
train_dataset = datamodule.train_data

# Access the dataloaders
train_dataloader = datamodule.train_dataloader()

# Create the model and engine
model = WinClip(class_name="lasercut_plank")
engine = Engine(task="segmentation")

# Train a Patchcore model on the given datamodule
engine.train(datamodule=datamodule, model=model)

